# Splitting C string in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I would like to split a string similar to

```
'abc "defg hijk \\"l; mn\\" opqrs"; tuv'
```

into

```
(['abc', '"defg hijk \\"l; mn\\" opqrs"'], 33)
```

i.e. I don't want to break on semicolon inside (nested) quotes. What's the easiest way, tokenize? It doesn't hurt if it's fast, but short is better.

**Edit:** I forgot one more detail that makes it even more tricky. I need the position of the semicolon that is cutting off the string, or -1 if there is none. (I'm doing changes to legacy code that used to be recursive, but stackoverflowed when the string became very long.)

Comment: I'm not seeing what the difference is between the first and second string in the list.  explaining what this string is and why it is being split where you say you want it to be might help in working up a solution.

Comment: The second statement is a list of two strings with everything after the semicolon outside quotes cut off.

Comment: @chown: almost, it cuts off everything after unnested semicolon, splits on whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely there is an easy way to solve this without a proper parser. You could probably get away with a hand built parser that doesn't require tokenizing though.

Something like the following should be a good guide:

```
def parse(s):
    cur_s = []
    strings = []

    def flush_string():
        strings.push(''.join(cur_s))
        cur_s = []

    def handle_special_cases():
        # TODO: Fill this in

    for c in s:
        if c == ';':
            break
        elif c in ['\\' '"']:
            handle_special_cases()
        elif c == ' ':
            flush_string()
        else:
            cur_s.push(c)

    flush_string()
    return strings
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just did. Ugly and slow, I had hoped there would be something pythonic for me. :)

Comment: If you want something more "elegant" you can look into the built-in parsers that come with Python. You can feed them a grammar and they will generate a parser for you. The drawback is that they will probably require more code than a solution like the above.

Answer (score 0):

It's a stateful search, so simple stateless operations are not available.  Here's a simple char-by-char stateful evaluator that might meet your "short" without resorting to full tokenization/parsing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

inp="""abc "defg hijk \\"l; mn\\" opqrs"; tuv'`"""

def words_to_semi(inpstr):
    ret = ['']
    st8 = 1  # state: 1=reg, 2=in quotes, 3=escaped quote, 4=escaped reg, 0=end
    ops = { 1 : {' ': lambda c: (None,1),
                 '"': lambda c: (c,2),
                 ';': lambda c: ('',0),
                 '\\': lambda c: (c,4),
                 },
            2 : {'\\': lambda c: (c,3),
                 '"':  lambda c: (c,1),
                 },
            3 : {None: lambda c: (c,2)},
            4 : {None: lambda c: (c,1)},
            }
    pos = 0

    for C in inpstr:
        oc,st8 = ops[st8].get(C, ops[st8].get(None, lambda c:(c,st8)))(C)
        if not st8: break
        if oc is None:
            ret.append('')
        else:
            ret[-1] += oc
        pos = pos + 1
    return ret, pos

print str(words_to_semi(inp))
```

Just modify the ops dict (and add new states) to handle other cases; everything else is generic code.

Comment: Looks neat and works for the simple case but was slow and didn't catch everything IRL, and was slower than brute-force. So I won't spend time fixing, but thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the brute-force method I went with. Brrr...

```
def f(s):
    instr = False
    inescape = False
    a = ''
    rs = []
    cut_index = -1
    for idx,ch in enumerate(s):
        if instr:
            a += ch
            if inescape:
                inescape = False
            elif ch == '\\':
                inescape = True
            elif ch == '"':
                if a:
                    rs += [a]
                    a = ''
                instr = False
        elif ch == '"':
            if a:
                rs += [a]
            a = ch
            instr = True
        elif ch == ';':
            if a:
                rs += [a]
            cut_index = idx
            break
        elif ch == ' ' or ch == '\t' or ch == '\n':
            if a:
                rs += [a]
                a = ''
        else:
            a += ch
    return rs, cut_index

f('abc "defg hijk \\"l; mn\\" opqrs"; tuv')
```